# How to trigger certain code depending on the user's tabItem choice in R-Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, tabitem

I would like to execute a block of commands when the user selects a specific "tabItem" from my "sidebarmenu". How can I trigger this chain of events?

```
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("File", tabName = "tabFile"),
  menuItem("Data", tabName = "tabData")
)

...

observe({
  if(input$tabFile==TRUE) { a-block-of-commands }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in `?sidebarMenu`.

```
sidebarMenu(
  id = "tabs", 
  menuItem("File", tabName = "tabFile"),
  menuItem("Data", tabName = "tabData")
)

...

observe({
  if(input$tabs == "tabFile") { a-block-of-commands }
})
```